# Core Text paragraph inside a UIScrollView is blurry

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, core-text, blurry

I tried drawing a long paragraph as an NSAttributedString in a view inside a UIScrollView. Weird thing is, the top of the paragraph is not blurry, but the more I scroll to the bottom the blurrier it gets ! I am well aware of the small issues you can have with Quartz and floats, therefore I tried to set the frame of the view 0.5 points below. Now the top of my paragraph is blurry, and the bottom is OK (!) I really don't know how to fix this, and would appreciate any help !

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every problem I've had to do with blurry text has always been to do with positioning the text at a sub-pixel offset. Somewhere, you probably have a position that isn't a whole number, and you should round it up or down. Places you might want to check:

- The position of your `UIScrollView`
- The contentOffset of your scroll view
- The position of the view that you override `drawRect` in
- The rect (path) that you actually draw into for your CoreText calls

I realise that this question is a few months old, but though it would be useful to have an answer anyway!

Comment: I did forgot to floor some values in my CoreText bounding path frame, thx for your answer!