# Disable blending when drawing with CoreText

Tags: ios, swift, core-text

I'm drawing black text on a gray background using CoreText. 
It seems that the system automatically does some blending on the glyphs, i'd like to disable this behavior if possible but I'm not sure how.

this is a zoomed-in screenshot of the top of the letter L. this is the blending i'd like to disable

[image]

The drawing code looks like:

```
let para = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    para.alignment = .center

    let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: Configuration.trainString,
                                        attributes:  [
                                            .font:UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: size.height*0.8),
                                            .paragraphStyle:para
        ])

    let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString as CFAttributedString)

    let frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, attrString.length), path, nil)

    CTFrameDraw(frame, ctx)

    let cgImage = ctx.makeImage()

    return cgImage
```

is there a way to do this while still leveraging CoreText?

**EDIT**: it is possible [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754665/core-text-paragraph-inside-a-uiscrollview-is-blurry) is related, however I believe this question is still valid. this question can be answered explicitly with code, whereas no code was provided before. I am already rounding the path used by the framesetter to integrals (as well as the font size)

a full gist of the code that will run in a Swift playground is posted [HERE](https://gist.github.com/rockshassa/6fe0bb6ab2f632d0a1f960f91145fe61)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core Text paragraph inside a UIScrollView is blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754665/core-text-paragraph-inside-a-uiscrollview-is-blurry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem obvious, but it bears worth repeating that [`CTFrameDraw(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1509589-ctframedraw) is ultimately just performing operations on [`CGContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext) so its text functions are essential.

Depending on the specifics of what you want I suggest you experiment with the font smoothing functions on `CGContext` starting with [`setAllowsFontSmoothing(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1454767-setallowsfontsmoothing).

**EDIT**

Using your playground I found a specific solution. Add setAllowsAntialiasing just before drawing your text:

```swift
ctx.setAllowsAntialiasing(false)
CTFrameDraw(frame, ctx)
```